# File rewrite not working?

Tags: php, file

test.php

```
<?php
$filec = fopen('test.txt','w');

$arr = file('test.txt');

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($filec,$value);
}

fclose($filec);
?>
```

test.txt

```
asdjlaksjd
asdhfwejkyhtjkre
jfdhgdjkf'hgjldsff
sfjnkbnm,cv
sm,nxcm,b,
sdjlhfskld
jfsdfwerwlur
slfdjsdkljfklsdjf
```

When I run test.php, test.txt is emptied. Does anyone know why?

Echoing $value, etc seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `fopen` with `w`, you are effectively clearing the file.  When you call `file`, you're reading from that cleared file.

Put the `file` call before the `fopen` one.